# Filter an Array of Objects based on a conditional property

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I have the following code:

```
const filterTable = (tableData, search) => {
    return tableData.filter(
        (data) =>
            !search || data.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()),
    )
}
```

And I want to make the **"name"** prop be something dynamic based on an **filterBy** param, something like that:

```
const filterTable = (tableData, search, filterBy) => {
    return tableData.filter(
        (data) =>
            !search || data.filterBy.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()),
    )
}
```

**Example 1:** considering that filterBy can be **"description"** instead **"name"** the final result is:

```
const filterTable = (tableData, search, filterBy) => {
    return tableData.filter(
        (data) =>
            !search || data.description.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()),
    )
}
```

**Example 2:** considering that filterBy can be **"state.city"** instead **"description"** the final result is:

```
const filterTable = (tableData, search, filterBy) => {
    return tableData.filter(
        (data) =>
            !search || data.state.city.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()),
    )
}
```

***Example 2** wont work when I pass nested object **"state.city"**.*

There's any way to do it? Glad for any help!

Comment: `const filterTable = (tableData, search, filterBy) =>` and `data[filterBy].toLowerCase()`

Comment: Oh, thx @Roberto, that worked!

Also, can you tell me if there's a way to make this work if I need to access nested objects in data?

Something like: filterTable(arr, attr, state.city)

Comment: Can you expand on that? I don't get the question. Examples would help

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question! :D

Comment: Pass a callback. `filterBy = (data) => data.state.city;` and then `|| filteryBy(data).toLowerCase()...`

Comment: @c-2k ... at the latest when the OP wants to filter by a nested 'data' property, the OP has to choose *pilchard's* approach which is function based ... one has to pass a function which does access the correct property from `data` and which will be invoked from within the OP's filter function.

Comment: Ty you'll guys, pilchard's approach worked like a charm!